# is it possible to save the value of a combo box together with a textbox in a single column in sql database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, combobox

i have a question.
is it possible to save data from combo box and textbox in to a database?
what i mean is this.

[image: giving the content of the texbox and combo box at one column]

i want to incorporate these two boxes, its like
(combo box + text box values)  = 1 value column in database.

before it is just this.

[image: only a textbox per column]

that period stands for semester period.

here is my present code for inserting the data.

could someone pls help me .. ? big thanks in advance.

```
 Try
        Dim connstr As String = "server=midtelephone\sqlexpress; database=testdb; user= sa; password=sa;"
        Dim cmdconn As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmdconn.ConnectionString = connstr
        cmd = New SqlCommand
        cmdconn.Open()
        'Dim period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO, who_updated, claim_no, year_student As String






        cmd.Connection = cmdconn

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY(period, vouch_amt, individual_amt, check_no, dir_no, d_mailed, who_updated, claim_no, year_student )" & _
            "values (@Period, @VOUCH_AMT, @individual_amt, @check_no, @DIR_NO, @D_MAILED, @who_updated, @claim_no, @year_student)"
        '1:

        If cmbPeriod.SelectedValue.ToString().Length = 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = txtPeriod.Text
        End If



        '2
        If txtVouch.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@vouch_amt", SqlDbType.Decimal) With {.Precision = 18, .Scale = 2}).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@vouch_amt", SqlDbType.Decimal) With {.Precision = 18, .Scale = 2}).Value = txtVouch.Text
        End If
        '3
        If txtIndividualamt.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@individual_amt", SqlDbType.Decimal) With {.Precision = 18, .Scale = 2}).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@individual_amt", SqlDbType.Decimal) With {.Precision = 18, .Scale = 2}).Value = txtIndividualamt.Text
        End If
        '4
        If txtDirno.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DIR_NO", SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DIR_NO", SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = txtDirno.Text
        End If
        '5
        If txtCheckno.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@check_no", SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@check_no", SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = txtCheckno.Text
        End If
        '6
        If txtDmailed.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@D_MAILED", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@D_MAILED", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtDmailed.Text
        End If
        '7
        If txtYrlvl.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@year_student", SqlDbType.Char, 10).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@year_student", SqlDbType.Char, 10).Value = txtYrlvl.Text
        End If
        '8
        If txtClaimno.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
            'cmd.Parameters.Add("@claim_no", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16).Value = DBNull.Value
            MsgBox("cannot proceed without beneficiary claim number!")
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@claim_no", SqlDbType.VarChar, 16).Value = txtClaimno.Text
        End If
        '9
        If txtUpdatedby.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@who_updated", SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@who_updated", SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = txtUpdatedby.Text
        End If


        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > -1 Then
            MsgBox("Saved")
        End If

        'End If
        cmdconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: why? i really need to incorporate those. :(

Comment: @Mitch is right, you really shouldn't do that 'cause you are de-normalizing your database.

Comment: hmm.. i see. do have any other idea on how will i work out on that problem? i want to use combo box and textbox instead of a single textbox. :/

Comment: hi guys .. i'm new here. can i ask a question? is it possible to combine the values of a combo box and a text box into a single column in database? its like > combobox value + textbox value = 1 Column in a database. im trying to combine two boxes into 1 value its like, ( in combo box, i would choose a value with regards to semesters (1st sem, 2nd sem, ETC,), and then the textbox serves as the school year (SY2012-2013) so if these two values will be joined together it'll be  e.g "1st sem SY2012-2013" something like that) can the two values be combined as 1 to my column period? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Got the answer now. it is possible.
i combined my textbox and combo box like this..

```
If cbPeriod.Text.Trim = "" Or txtSyear.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Period and School Year cannot be empty")
            Me.Focus()
        Else
            If MsgBox("You are about to add a new detail with a period of '" + cbPeriod.Text + "' and SY '" + txtSyear.Text + "' (changes with period cannot be modified once inserted) ", CType(MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2 + MsgBoxStyle.Question, MsgBoxStyle), "update") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = cbPeriod.Text + txtSyear.Text
            End If
        End If
```

thanks guys.